# How to remove Add to Cart on Woocommerce 3.3.4

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

So i'm setting up an external link products (affiliate), and i've been trying to remove add to cart from the website with no luck. I've tried many solutions, but none worked. Either they pop html 500, or they break a page, or simply don't work. Also plugins for that do not work. Is there any way i can get it done? 
Theme i'm using is Exzo:
https://themeforest.net/item/modern-electronics-ecommerce-wordpress-woocommerce-theme-exzo/19356950

Solutions i tried:

```
// Replace add to cart button by a linked button to the product in Shop and archives pages

add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    // Not needed for variable products
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return $button;

// Button text here
$button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );

return '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
```

}

Then

```
add_filter( ‘woocommerce_is_purchasable’, false );
```

Also

```
function WpBlog() {
remove_action( ‘woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item’, ‘woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart’);
remove_action( ‘woocommerce_single_product_summary’, ‘woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart’);
return WooCommerce::instance();
}
```

And woocommerce.php doesnt have over 900 lines needed for this one

```
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

Comment: The guilty is your theme that make customizations on that and don't allow proven working codes to work in your case… So you should better look in your theme, trying to solve that problem, as no answers will make the trick… This question has been answered a lot and a lot of recent answers just works with 3.3+ … To finish this question is not detailed regarding, the theme used and the related plugins used… **You should better add in your question, those details and the codes that you have tried yet.**

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, edited my post.

Comment: The first code is from me and works on all normal themes as Storefront with WC version 3.3.4… It replace add to cart button on shop by a linked button to the product. If this code don't work on your commercial theme, **you should better contact theme authors support threads***… StackOverFlow don't handle any software support…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );
function remove_add_to_cart_buttons( $button ) {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    return $button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck with this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-affiliates/

If that doesn't work, can you override the add to cart templates in your theme?